# Manipulate innerText of a CKEditor ViewElement

Tags: ckeditor5, neoscms, ckeditor5-plugin

I am creating a little custom plugin for the CKEditor5 for the #neoscms.
Neos is using the #ckeditor5 but with a custom view.

The plugin is more or less a placeholder plugin. The user can configure a data-source with a key value store for items (identifier and labels). The dropdown in the CKEditor is filled with the items and when the user selects an item from the dropdown, it creates a placeholder element that should end in a span element with some data-attributes.

The main idea was to have an empty element and just data-attributes to identify the element and being able to assign live data. But it turns out that the live data thing is tricky. When I manipulate the span with an extra JS snippet on the Website, the CKEditor cannot handle this.

Is it possible to manipulate a view element in the DOM and still have a working Editor?
The Plugin works fine if I just add inner Text in the downCasting and don't replace something. But the live data would be nice.

[Neos Backend with a element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLOGD.png)

Maybe that code gives an idea of the package.
It is not ready yet as this is more or less the main feature ;)

```
import {Plugin, toWidget, viewToModelPositionOutsideModelElement, Widget,} from "ckeditor5-exports";

import PlaceholderCommand from "./placeHolderCommand";

export default class PlaceholderEditing extends Plugin {
    static get requires() {
        return [Widget];
    }

    init() {
        this._defineSchema();
        this._defineConverters();

        this.editor.commands.add(
            "placeholder",
            new PlaceholderCommand(this.editor)
        );

        this.editor.editing.mapper.on(
            "viewToModelPosition",
            viewToModelPositionOutsideModelElement(this.editor.model, (viewElement) =>
                viewElement.hasClass("internezzo-placeholder")
            )
        );

        this.editor.config.define("placeholderProps", {
            types: ["name", "node", "nodePath"],
        });

        this.editor.config.define("placeholderBrackets", {
            open: "[",
            close: "]",
        });
    }

    _defineSchema() {
        const schema = this.editor.model.schema;

        schema.register("placeholder", {
            allowWhere: "$text",
            isInline: true,
            isObject: true,
            allowAttributes: [
                "name",
                "node",
                "nodePath",
                "data-placeholder-identifier",
                "data-node-identifier",
                "data-node-path",
            ],
        });
    }

    _defineConverters() {
        const conversion = this.editor.conversion;
        const config = this.editor.config;

        conversion.for("upcast").elementToElement({
            view: {
                name: "span",
                classes: ["foobar-placeholder"],
            },
            model: (viewElement, writer) => {
                const name = viewElement.getAttribute('data-placeholder-identifier');
                const node = viewElement.getAttribute('data-node-identifier');
                const nodePath = viewElement.getAttribute('data-node-path');
                const modelWriter = writer.writer || writer;
                return modelWriter.createElement("placeholder", {name, node, nodePath, editable: false});
            },
        });

        conversion.for("editingDowncast").elementToElement({
            model: "placeholder",
            view: (modelItem, writer) => {
                const viewWriter = writer.writer || writer;
                const widgetElement = createPlaceholderView(modelItem, viewWriter);
                return toWidget(widgetElement, viewWriter);
            },
        });

        conversion.for("dataDowncast").elementToElement({
            model: "placeholder",
            view: (modelItem, writer) => {
                const viewWriter = writer.writer || writer;

                return createPlaceholderView(modelItem, viewWriter);
            },
        });

        // Helper method for downcast converters.
        function createPlaceholderView(modelItem, viewWriter) {
            const name = modelItem.getAttribute("name");
            const node = modelItem.getAttribute("node");
            const nodePath = modelItem.getAttribute("nodePath");

            const placeholderView = viewWriter.createContainerElement("span", {
                class: "foobar-placeholder",
                "data-placeholder-identifier": name,
                "data-node-identifier": node,
                "data-node-path": nodePath,
            });

            // Would be nice to remove that and have just empty spans that get dynamic data
            let innerText = config.get("placeholderBrackets.open") + name;
            innerText += config.get("placeholderBrackets.close");
            viewWriter.insert(
                viewWriter.createPositionAt(placeholderView, 0),
                viewWriter.createText(innerText)
            );

            return placeholderView;
        }
    }
}
```

So, the extra JS snippet that is used by the website is searching for spans with the class `foobar-placeholder` and writes a value with live data into the span. That works in the frontend, of course, but the backend of the CMS that uses CKEditor has issues with the changing data.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution with docs of CKEditor, and maybe I misuse the API somehow, but I now found a working solution for me.

My website snippet is now communicating with the Plugin via Broadcast messages. And then I search for placeholder elements and check if I need to change an attribute.

```
const broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('placeholder:changeData');
broadcastChannel.postMessage({identifier: name, value});
```

And in the plugin

```
// Receive new values for placeholder via broadcast
        const broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('placeholder:changeData');
        broadcastChannel.onmessage = (message) => {
            const identifier = get('data.identifier', message);
            const newValue = get('data.value', message);
            this.editor.model.change( writer => {
                if (identifier) {
                    this._replaceAttribute(writer, identifier, newValue);
                }
            });
        };
```

Only downside now is that I need to reload the page, but already read that this is maybe cause by my element down casting and I change attributes.